# Problems with deploying flask WSGI application on apache2

Tags: python, apache2, flask, wsgi

I created a one file Flask app so I can test how to deploy it on apache2 server. I followed the steps on the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#installing-mod-wsgi) as far as the server and WSGI configuration goes. When I point to the resource in the browser it says I have no permissions. WSGI daemon is given the same permissions as the Flask app. Below is the VirtualHost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost 

WSGIDaemonProcess flask_test user=someuser group=someuser threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /flask_test/ /var/www/flask_test/flask_test.wsgi

DocumentRoot /var/www/flask_test/
ErrorLog /var/www/flask_test/logs/error.log

    <Directory /var/www/flask_test/>
        WSGIProcessGroup flask_test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the WSGI file

```
import sys

activate_this = '/home/someuser/pyProjects/general/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.append('/home/someuser/pyProjects')

from general import test as application
```

And finally the output from error.log

```
[Tue Jul 31 01:51:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140345719740224,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Tue Jul 31 01:51:21 2012] [error] [client 108.207.222.48] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/flask_test/flask_test.wsgi
[Tue Jul 31 01:51:21 2012] [error] [client 108.207.222.48] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/flask_test/favicon.ico
```

EDIT: After implementing Graham Dumpleton suggestions server now returns code 500 with following error 
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in .wsgi file.
I didn't import the app object correctly. Basically you want to make sure that app object is imported as application in your wsgi. For example `from flask_test import app as application`

Answer (score 2):

Generally want:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /flask_test/ /var/www/flask_test/flask_test.wsgi
```

No trailing slash on the mount point for a sub URL.

Worse is that you have:

```
Deny from all
```

So you are explicitly telling Apache to return forbidden.

You should have:

```
Allow from all
```

in that context.

Comment: Thanks. I applied your suggestions and it seems I'm getting closer. Now I'm getting 500 error and in error.log `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` in error log. Is there a way to get more detailed output?